BillingCity field in not available for selection in Quote Object
I'm configuring the default Search layout in Quote layout to have BillingCity field but am not able to find this field in Available fields section to move it to selected fields. I've attached the screenshot of my Org setup. Any thoughts on what I might be missing. Thanks!

